# ArgumentError - unknown SSL method `TLSv1_2'

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to move my AWS integration over TLS instead of SSLv3, but I'm receiving an error when trying to set the config.fog_credentials as another SO post has suggested, but I am receiving the ArgumentError above (unknown SSL method 'TLSv1_2'.  I am open to a different solution to move the requests over TLS as well.

```
config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region:                ENV['AWS_REGION'],
      connection_options:    { ssl_version: :TLSv1_2 }
    }
```

## Gemfile.lock

```
carrierwave (0.10.0)
excon (0.45.3)
fog (1.31.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting it inside the fog_credentials hash, try setting it afterwards on config itself with the following 2 lines:

```
config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 600
config.fog_attributes = { ssl_version: :TLSv1_2 }
```